# Autenticação com JWT Auth e dingo API Laravel 5.4

Tags: web-service, api, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-auth

Eu fiz uma autenticação com a model user padrão do Laravel 5.4, porém agora, eu fiz a mesma implementação, só que com uma model personalizada, e não ta dando certo. Me retorna esse erro `"message": "Undefined index: password"`. 
Model:

```
    <?php

namespace ForcaVendas\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Usuario extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'UsuarioID', 'Nome', 'Login',
        'Genero', 'Email', 'Status', 'Administrador'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [ 'Senha' ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'UsuarioID';
    protected $table = 'Usuarios';
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->UsuarioID;
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [
            'Usuario' => [
                'UsuarioID' => $this->UsuarioID,
                'Nome' => $this->Nome,
                'Genero' => $this->Genero,
                'Email' => $this->Email,
                'Status' => $this->Status,
                'Administrador' => $this->Administrador
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

AuthController:

```
    <?php

namespace ForcaVendas\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use ForcaVendas\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function username()
    {
        return 'Login';
    }

    public function password()
    {
        return 'Senha';
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), $this->password());
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            $this->password() => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    public function accessToken(Request $request)
    {
        //se faltar informação, pro método validateLogin
        // nem segue pros passos abaixo
        $this->validateLogin($request);
        $credenciais = $this->credentials($request);

        if ($token = \Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credenciais))
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request, $token);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    public function atualizarToken(Request $request)
    {
        $token = \Auth::guard('api')->refresh();
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request, $token);
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request, $token)
    {
        return ['token' => $token];
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'erro' => \Lang::get('auth.failed')
        ], 400);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        \Auth::guard('api')->logout();
        return response()->json([], 204);
    }
}
```

Api (rotas):

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

\ApiRoute::version('v1', function(){
    \ApiRoute::group(['namespace' => 'ForcaVendas\Http\Controllers\Api',
                      'as' => 'api'
    ], function(){
        \ApiRoute::post('/acesso_token', [
            'uses' => 'AuthController@accessToken',
            'middleware' => 'api.throttle',
            'limit' => 10,  //qnt requisições
            'expires' => 1  //em X(1) tempo
        ])->name('.access_token');

        \ApiRoute::post('/atualizar_token', [
            'uses' => 'AuthController@atualizarToken',
            'middleware' => 'api.throttle',
            'limit' => 10,  //qnt requisições
            'expires' => 1  //em X(1) tempo
        ])->name('.atualizar_token');

        \ApiRoute::group([
            'middleware' => ['api.throttle', 'api.auth'], 'limit' => 100, 'expires' => 3
        ], function(){
            //Rotas que precisarão de autenticação
            ApiRoute::post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
            ApiRoute::get('/teste', function(){
               return 'Autenticado';
            });
        });
    });
});
```

config/auth.php:

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => ForcaVendas\Models\Usuario::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

config/api.php:

```
    <?php


return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Standards Tree
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Versioning an API with Dingo revolves around content negotiation and
    | custom MIME types. A custom type will belong to one of three
    | standards trees, the Vendor tree (vnd), the Personal tree
    | (prs), and the Unregistered tree (x).
    |
    | By default the Unregistered tree (x) is used, however, should you wish
    | to you can register your type with the IANA. For more details:
    | https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6838
    |
    */

    'standardsTree' => env('API_STANDARDS_TREE', 'x'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Subtype
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Your subtype will follow the standards tree you use when used in the
    | "Accept" header to negotiate the content type and version.
    |
    | For example: Accept: application/x.SUBTYPE.v1+json
    |
    */

    'subtype' => env('API_SUBTYPE', ''),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default API Version
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the default version when strict mode is disabled and your API
    | is accessed via a web browser. It's also used as the default version
    | when generating your APIs documentation.
    |
    */

    'version' => env('API_VERSION', 'v1'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default API Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | A default prefix to use for your API routes so you don't have to
    | specify it for each group.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env('API_PREFIX', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default API Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | A default domain to use for your API routes so you don't have to
    | specify it for each group.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('API_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When documenting your API using the API Blueprint syntax you can
    | configure a default name to avoid having to manually specify
    | one when using the command.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('API_NAME', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Conditional Requests
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Globally enable conditional requests so that an ETag header is added to
    | any successful response. Subsequent requests will perform a check and
    | will return a 304 Not Modified. This can also be enabled or disabled
    | on certain groups or routes.
    |
    */

    'conditionalRequest' => env('API_CONDITIONAL_REQUEST', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Strict Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enabling strict mode will require clients to send a valid Accept header
    | with every request. This also voids the default API version, meaning
    | your API will not be browsable via a web browser.
    |
    */

    'strict' => env('API_STRICT', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enabling debug mode will result in error responses caused by thrown
    | exceptions to have a "debug" key that will be populated with
    | more detailed information on the exception.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('API_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Generic Error Format
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When some HTTP exceptions are not caught and dealt with the API will
    | generate a generic error response in the format provided. Any
    | keys that aren't replaced with corresponding values will be
    | removed from the final response.
    |
    */

    'errorFormat' => [
        'message' => ':message',
        'errors' => ':errors',
        'code' => ':code',
        'status_code' => ':status_code',
        'debug' => ':debug',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Middleware that will be applied globally to all API requests.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The authentication providers that should be used when attempting to
    | authenticate an incoming API request.
    |
    */

    'auth' => [
        'jwt' => \ForcaVendas\Autenticacao\JWTProvider::class
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Throttling / Rate Limiting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Consumers of your API can be limited to the amount of requests they can
    | make. You can create your own throttles or simply change the default
    | throttles.
    |
    */

    'throttling' => [

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Response Transformer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Responses can be transformed so that they are easier to format. By
    | default a Fractal transformer will be used to transform any
    | responses prior to formatting. You can easily replace
    | this with your own transformer.
    |
    */

    'transformer' => env('API_TRANSFORMER', Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal::class),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Response Formats
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Responses can be returned in multiple formats by registering different
    | response formatters. You can also customize an existing response
    | formatter.
    |
    */

    'defaultFormat' => env('API_DEFAULT_FORMAT', 'json'),

    'formats' => [

        'json' => Dingo\Api\Http\Response\Format\Json::class,

    ],

];
```

config/jwt.php:

```
    <?php

/*
 * This file is part of jwt-auth.
 *
 * (c) Sean Tymon <tymon148@gmail.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT Authentication Secret
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Don't forget to set this in your .env file, as it will be used to sign
    | your tokens. A helper command is provided for this:
    | `php artisan jwt:secret`
    |
    | Note: This will be used for Symmetric algorithms only (HMAC),
    | since RSA and ECDSA use a private/public key combo (See below).
    |
    */

    'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT Authentication Keys
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The algorithm you are using, will determine whether your tokens are
    | signed with a random string (defined in `JWT_SECRET`) or using the
    | following public & private keys.
    |
    | Symmetric Algorithms:
    | HS256, HS384 & HS512 will use `JWT_SECRET`.
    |
    | Asymmetric Algorithms:
    | RS256, RS384 & RS512 / ES256, ES384 & ES512 will use the keys below.
    |
    */

    'keys' => [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Public Key
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | A path or resource to your public key.
        |
        | E.g. 'file://path/to/public/key'
        |
        */

        'public' => env('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'),

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Private Key
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | A path or resource to your private key.
        |
        | E.g. 'file://path/to/private/key'
        |
        */

        'private' => env('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'),

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Passphrase
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | The passphrase for your private key. Can be null if none set.
        |
        */

        'passphrase' => env('JWT_PASSPHRASE'),

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT time to live
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token will be valid for.
    | Defaults to 1 hour.
    |
    | You can also set this to null, to yield a never expiring token.
    | Some people may want this behaviour for e.g. a mobile app.
    | This is not particularly recommended, so make sure you have appropriate
    | systems in place to revoke the token if necessary.
    |
    */

    'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Refresh time to live
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token can be refreshed
    | within. I.E. The user can refresh their token within a 2 week window of
    | the original token being created until they must re-authenticate.
    | Defaults to 2 weeks.
    |
    | You can also set this to null, to yield an infinite refresh time.
    | Some may want this instead of never expiring tokens for e.g. a mobile app.
    | This is not particularly recommended, so make sure you have appropriate
    | systems in place to revoke the token if necessary.
    |
    */

    'refresh_ttl' => env('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT hashing algorithm
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the hashing algorithm that will be used to sign the token.
    |
    | See here: https://github.com/namshi/jose/tree/master/src/Namshi/JOSE/Signer/OpenSSL
    | for possible values.
    |
    */

    'algo' => env('JWT_ALGO', 'HS256'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Required Claims
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the required claims that must exist in any token.
    | A TokenInvalidException will be thrown if any of these claims are not
    | present in the payload.
    |
    */

    'required_claims' => [
        'iss',
        'iat',
        'exp',
        'nbf',
        'sub',
        'jti',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Persistent Claims
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the claim keys to be persisted when refreshing a token.
    | `sub` and `iat` will automatically be persisted, in
    | addition to the these claims.
    |
    | Note: If a claim does not exist then it will be ignored.
    |
    */

    'persistent_claims' => [
        // 'foo',
        // 'bar',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Blacklist Enabled
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | In order to invalidate tokens, you must have the blacklist enabled.
    | If you do not want or need this functionality, then set this to false.
    |
    */

    'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),

    /*
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Blacklist Grace Period
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When multiple concurrent requests are made with the same JWT,
    | it is possible that some of them fail, due to token regeneration
    | on every request.
    |
    | Set grace period in seconds to prevent parallel request failure.
    |
    */

    'blacklist_grace_period' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD', 0),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the various providers used throughout the package.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | JWT Provider
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Specify the provider that is used to create and decode the tokens.
        |
        */

        'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Authentication Provider
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Specify the provider that is used to authenticate users.
        |
        */

        'auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate::class,

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Storage Provider
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Specify the provider that is used to store tokens in the blacklist.
        |
        */

        'storage' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate::class,

    ],

];
```

PS: No AuthController, estou sobrescrevendo os métodos para pegar meus campos personalizados, no caso 'Login' e 'Senha', não entendo porque ele ainda está pegando 'password'.

Comment: O padrão é password no código é isso, e você está usando `Senha` a autenticação deve ser feita de outra forma: leia https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: Entendi, mas porque o username eu posso mandar como Login na requisição e o password eu tenho que manter password? Vou ler essa parte da documentação, obrigado!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic desculpe a minha ignorancia, mas lendo a documentação eu não consegui entender o porquê disso. Eu precisei colocar também esse trecho na minha model:

    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->Senha;
    }