# Relação many to many com id do tipo UUID Laravel 5.4 Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Eu estou seguindo a documentação do Laravel para fazer essa relação com o tipo do id uuid.
Nos métodos do relacionamento eu especifiquei a tabela pivô e os campos IDS, no entanto fui debugar no tinker para ver se estava realmente funcionando e ele me retorna isso `PHP error:  Call to undefined function ForcaVendas\Models\belongsToMany() in /Users/matheus/Documents/ForcaVendas/app/Models/Sistemas/Usuario.php on line 21` quando vou faço esse código no tinker: PS:Ele instancia os objetos.

```
$usuario = ForcaVendas\Models\Usuario::find('um guid correspondente');
$grupoUsuario = new ForcaVendas\Models\GrupoUsuario;
$grupoUsuario->usuarios()->attach($usuario);
```

Migration grupos usuarios:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGruposUsuariosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('GruposUsuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('GrupoUsuarioID')->primary();
            $table->string('Descricao', 100)->index();
            $table->text('Descritivo');
            $table->boolean('Status')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('GruposUsuarios');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```

Migration usuários:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsuariosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('UsuarioID')->primary();
            $table->string('Nome', 100);
            $table->string('Login', 100)->unique();
            $table->string('Senha', 100);
            $table->char('Genero', 1);
            $table->string('Email', 100);
            $table->boolean('Status')->default(true);
            $table->boolean('Administrador')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('Usuarios');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```

migration pivô (GruposUsuariosMembros):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGruposUsuariosMembrosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('GruposUsuariosMembros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('GrupoUsuarioMembroID');
            $table->uuid('GrupoUsuarioID')->index();
            $table->uuid('UsuarioID')->index();
            $table->foreign('GrupoUsuarioID')->references('GrupoUsuarioID')->on('GruposUsuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('UsuarioID')->references('UsuarioID')->on('Usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('GruposUsuariosMembros');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```

Método de relacionamento na model usuario:

```
public function gruposUsuarios()
{
    return belongsToMany('ForcaVendas\Models\GrupoUsuario', 'GruposUsuariosMembros', 'UsuarioID', 'GrupoMembroID');
}
```

Método de relacionamento na model grupo usuario:

```
public function usuarios()
{
        return belongsToMany(Usuario::class, 'GruposUsuariosMembros', 'GrupoUsuarioID', 'UsuarioID');
}
```

Fiz isso me baseando na documentação do Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente não existe isso: `ForcaVendas\Models\belongsToMany()` pelo menos no pacote do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) é só colocar `this->belongsToMany` e conferir as configurações se estão corretas, exemplo:

`Model` ***GrupoUsuario***

```
public function usuarios()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Usuario::class, 
              'GruposUsuariosMembros', 
              'GrupoUsuarioID', 
              'UsuarioID');
}
```

`Model` ***Usuario***

```
public function gruposUsuarios()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(GrupoUsuario::class,
        'GruposUsuariosMembros', 
        'UsuarioID', 
        'GrupoUsuarioID');
}
```

***Referencia:*** [Eloquent Relationships Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Peço perdão, me esqueci do $this->.
Sera que poderia me ajudar com outra questão?https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226294/autenticação-com-jwt-auth-e-dingo-api-laravel-5-4